# Linq to Entities - group by on multiple joined tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a query which joins several tables.  I then need to group by just the first 2 columns and then select the values of the rest.  Right now it is working fine for the first 4 columns but then the group by stops working for all columns.  I have used a similar query before and it has worked fine so if anyone has any insight, it would be much appreciated.

```
var query = (from p in context.Process
    join pf in context.table on p.ProcessID equals pf.ProcessID
    join f in context.Flows on pf.FlowID equals f.FlowID
    join d in context.Directions on pf.DirectionID equals d.DirectionID
    join ft in context.FlowTypes on f.FlowTypeID equals ft.FlowTypeID
    join fp in context.FlowProperties on f.FlowPropertyID equals fp.FlowPropertyID
    join ug in context.UnitGroups on fp.UnitGroupID equals ug.UnitGroupID
    group new { p, pf, f, d, ft, fp, ug} by new
    {                             
        FlowPropertyName = fp.Name,
        ug.ReferenceUnit,
        FlowDirection = d.FlowDirection,
        FlowType = ft.Type,
        //Won't group on these 3 column
        //ProcessFlowResult =pf.Result,
        //FlowName = f.Name,
        //ProcessFlowID = pf.ProcessFlowID, 
    } into g
    select new Model
    {
        FlowPropertyName = g.Key.FlowPropertyName,
        ReferenceUnit = g.Key.ReferenceUnit,
        FlowDirection = g.Key.FlowDirection,
        FlowType = g.Key.FlowType,
        //ProcessFlowResult = g.Key.ProcessFlowResult,
        //FlowName = g.Key.FlowName,
        //ProcessFlowID = g.Key.ProcessFlowID
    }).AsQueryable();
return query;
```

Comment: should the 2nd line of your query be something like: `join pf in context.ProcessFlows...` ? it can't be what you've pasted as you'd be using the alias `p` twice...

Comment: First start using navigation properties in stead of joins. Then see if the problem persists.

Comment: James - I just looked at my query *hoping* that the issue was something that easy (and stupid) but it has that aliased as "pf".  I'm not sure how it got pasted in as "p" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Here's a scaled down lambda version of the solution, using navigation properties ;-), just in case anyone else is looking for something similar.

```
 var query = context.ProcessFlows
                .GroupBy(p => new
                {
                 FlowPropertyName = p.Flow.FlowProperty.Name
                 })
                .SelectMany(pf => pf.Select(p => new IntermediateFlow
                {
                    FlowPropertyName = p.Flow.FlowProperty.Name,
                    ReferenceUnit = p.Flow.FlowProperty.UnitGroup.Name
                })).AsQueryable();
            return query.OrderBy(pFlow => new { pFlow.FlowPropertyName, pFlow.ReferenceUnit });
```